# HTML: Как сделать так, чтобы текст не выпадал из блока

Tags: html, css

Можно ли сделать так, что когда текст достигает края блока, он не выходит за него, а переносится на новую строку?

```html
<div class="post-text"></div>
```

текст задаю в JS. И кусок CSS:

```js
"text": "kokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokokkokokokokokokkokokokokokokokokokokko
```

```css
.post-text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-bottom: -60px;
    padding: 5px;
    font: bond 12px Arial;
    border: 1px solid #0960bb;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `.post-text` добавьте `word-wrap: break-word;`

```
.post-text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-bottom: -60px;
    padding: 5px;
    font: bond 12px Arial;
    border: 1px solid #0960bb;
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```